# Intensive testing of a function using mocha , node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mocha.js, chai

i am trying to write a unit test for my node.js code . I am able to write the test for a function but i want to test each network query(query fetching data from DB) whether they are returning desired response or not.
I am sharing my node.js code as well as my test code.

node.js code(routes.js)

```
module.exports = {
   getUser: {
        get: function(req, parameters, environment) {

             var id = req.queryString.id;

                  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

                       db.tx(t =>{
                            return t.one("select configuration_value from fint.configuration where configuration_key='LOAN' and application_id =(select application_id from fint.application where application_name='Product Tailoring')")
                       })  
                       .then(conf => {
                            conf_key = conf.configuration_value;
                       }) 

                       db.tx(t =>{
                           return t.one("select smart_account_type_id from fint.smart_account_type where smart_account_type_name='LOAN'")
                       })  
                      .then(acc_type => {
                           smart_acc_type_id =  acc_type.smart_account_type_id;
                      })
                  }
        })
   }
}
```

This is a sample code, what exactly i want is to run the test on the individual queries instead of the whole function.

My test code (test.js)

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var chai = require('chai'); 
var app = require('../api/smartAccount/identifyLoan/getDirectDebitTrans/routes');

describe("Unit testing for function", function(){
    it("Testing the function using mocha", function(done){
        var req = {
            queryString: {
                uniqueUserId: 101
            }
        };

        var test = app.getUser.get(req);
        return expect(Promise.resolve(test)).to.have.property('_bitField');
        done();
    });
});
```

Any leads will be appreciated, and if anybody come across some links regarding the same, please share.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to test each query separately, I would refactor the code and wrap each query in a separate function. Thus, you will be able to do unit testing over real units. If you're not able to test a part of your app easily, it's probably because something isn't designed the right way. By the way, you return a promise that never resolves (or rejects)!?

About the unit testing with promise function, you could give a try to [co-mocha](https://github.com/blakeembrey/co-mocha). Using such a flow control framework will make your promise tests much more readable.

```
module.exports = {
  getUser: {
    get: function(req, parameters, environment) {
      var id = req.queryString.id;
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getConfKey(id)
        .then(confKey => {
          getAccType(id)
          .then(accType => {
            resolve({key: confKey, type: accType})
          })
        })
      })
    })

    getConfKey: function(id) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.tx(t =>{
          return t.one("select configuration_value from fint.configuration where configuration_key='LOAN' and application_id =(select application_id from fint.application where application_name='Product Tailoring')")
        })  
        .then(conf => {
          resolve(conf.configuration_value);
        })
      })
    }

    getAccType: function(id) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.tx(t =>{
          return t.one("select smart_account_type_id from fint.smart_account_type where smart_account_type_name='LOAN'")
        })  
        .then(acc_type => {
          resolve(acc_type.smart_account_type_id);
        })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this is an example. If both functions are independent, you can execute these concurrently. Concurrency is not the point of this question.

Comment: Thanks, it helped.
promise was resolving as well rejecting but i didnt put that part in the code as my major concern was testing the multiple network queries in a single function.
by the way just out of curiosity, is it possible to test multiple queries in a single function?

Comment: You can test whatever you want. Give an input, test the output.
But unit testing, by definition, is to test a single unit, and doing it this way will keep your tests simple and clear. Why do you want to test multiple queries in a single function ?

Comment: Actually its more of that i want to test functions inside function, i.e. i want to write my test case as such it test multiple functions inside my root function on which test case is been written. Can you provide a little knowledge on that?

Comment: I would start to **unit test** each sub-function. Once this is done, you can then perform some **functional tests** against your root function. This means that you give an input and independently of what is going on internally, you get your result.

Thus your are sure (1) that each sub-function does what it should do and (2) that the root function uses the sub-functions correctly and returns an appropriate result.